# JSON обработка строк

Tags: c#, json

Есть данные JSON, которые нужно перенести в базу.

```
{"catalog":{"categories":[{"id":"3","name":"Межкомнатные двери"},{"id":"301","name":"Аква Двери","parent_id":"300"}, ..
```

Соотвественно получаем данные:

```
string str;
            using (HttpClient http = new HttpClient())
            {
                str = http.GetStringAsync("https://...........").Result;
            }


            JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(str);

            var allUid = jObject["catalog"]["categories"].Select(n => n.ToString()).ToList();
            foreach (var catg in allUid)
            {
                JObject jObject2 = JObject.Parse(catg);
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    category.name = jObject2["name"].ToString();

                    if(?????(jObject2["parent_id"].ToString()))
                    {
                        category.parent_id = null;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        category.parent_id = jObject2["parent_id"].ToString();

                    }

                    _context.Add(category);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
            }
```

Но никак не могу найти, как обработать исключение NullReferenceException, при ссылке на parent_id. Поскольку в некоторых строках оно отсутствует полностью.
То есть как сделать вот эту проверку:

```
if(?????(jObject2["parent_id"].ToString()))
```

Comment: а простая проверка на null не рабоатет что ли? Проверьте есть ли такой ключ тогда. Если ключ есть, то обращайтесь к нему.

Comment: Да не работает, как я понимаю из за того что нет самого объекта который может быть равен нулю. В строке отсутствует parent_id соответственно и получается что объекта нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так можно например проверить:

```
if(!jObject2.HasKey["parent_id"]){
   category.parent_id = null;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но на HasKey - VS ругалось, оказывается можно упростить до jObject2["parent_id"] - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7216917/json-net-has-key-method

Comment: да, это наверно атрибут у jtoken'a. Прошу прощения. С Json вскольз работал.